# How do I really turn 3.7volts to 5 volts (simple explanation, please)

Tags: inductor

Look I understand a couple of things in electronics but I need clarity with this one thing. See for power banks to produce 5 V from 3.7 V, how exactly is an inductor used? I have a 5 V regular and I know how to use it but I need to know how I need to use the inductor to first step up my 3.7 V supply.

1. Do I connect the power source, inductor and capacitor in series then put the regulator across the capacitor to extract the output or combined power source + inductor output?
2. Do I add a transistor in the circuit and put an oscillating pulse at the base so the circuit can turn on and off, is that how you use inductors?
3. I need to know, to have more voltage in a circuit, do you connect everything and the output is made high or do you need to make the circuit go on and off first before you get a voltage higher than the power source?
4. How DO YOU USE AN INDUCTOR PLEASE? ON AND OFF OR JUST NORMAL UNINTERRUPTED DC SUPPLY?

Comment: Does the circuit need to oscillate or not?

Comment: "*I have a 5 V regular ...*" Do you mean a *regulator*? If so, then please give the part number and a link to the datasheet. Put the details in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/PSU/psu32.php

Comment: Many consider all caps to be yelling, and in this context it seems out of place and rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ever got that big voltage spike when de-energizing a relay without diode?
A boost converter uses exactly that effect.
Except instead of shorting this surge, it stores it in the capacitor. Controlled, many times a second.

[image]

I suggest you try to build one. Tip: [MC34063](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF)
[Tutorial by EEVBlog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGp82xhybs4)

Comment: You are a gift from God

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you seem to be interested about is called a boost converter. It does use a transistor to charge up energy into inductor from the lower voltage side, and release the energy to higher voltage side.